# Ruby Date and Time combination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would need to combine day and time into one variable in Ruby. I have already set up the following:

```
t.datetime "date"
t.datetime "start_time"
t.datetime "end_time"
```

I know that there are similar answers to this question available, but would someone be so kind to explain me WHAT exactly should I do to combine these(i.e run ruby with a specific command, modify certain files etc.)? I'm very new to Ruby, so it's hard for me to understand for now :(

Thanks very much in advance

Lilija

Comment: What do you mean when you say you'd like to "combine" them. `datetime` already contains both the date and the time.

Comment: A datetime column stores a specific time on a specific date. So it already is a date and a time in a single attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`date` contains date of event and you want to combine it to `start_time` ( let say they are the attributes of `some_model`

```
date = some_model.date.year #stores actual date of event with wrong time
start_time = some_model.start_time #stores actual start time of event with wrong date
end_time = some_model.end_time #stores actual end time of event with wrong date

combined_start_datetime = DateTime.new(date.year,date.month, date.day, start_time.hour, start_time.min)
combined_end_datetime = DateTime.new(date.year,date.month, date.day, end_time.hour, end_time.min)
```

**Note:** `datetime` contains both date and time.